# get data from 3 relational tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables Guardian, Student and StudentsGuardian. Table information is as under

```
Guardian:
 id(pk)

Student:
 id(pk)
 name
 address


StudentsGuardian:
  student_id(fk)
  guardian_id(fk)
```

I want to select those students whose guardian_id=2(suppose). Actually these are relational tables so i am unable to think a way to accomplish it. If i apply join it would return a joint table but i need only the information of those students having guardian_id= specific id.

It could be a basic question but i am stuck in it. Thanks

Comment: What SELECT statements and JOINS have you tried already? Why were the results not what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.address 
     FROM Student s 
      INNER JOIN StudentsGuardian sg ON s.id = sg.student_id 
       WHERE sg.guardian_id = 'somespecific_id'
```

Comment: Means i dont need to go through guardians table? Actually i was trying to access that table using Guardian table.

Comment: I wrote a messed up query thats y i could not share.

Comment: @jailedabroad as per your requirement there is no need of using the Guardian table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM  Guardian
INNER JOIN StudentsGuardian ON StudentsGuardian.guardian_id = Guardian.id
INNER JOIN Student ON Student.id = StudentsGuardian.student_id
WHERE StudentsGuardian.guardian_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Student.name, Student.address 
FROM Student JOIN StudentsGuardian ON Student.id = StudentsGuardian.student_id
WHERE StudentsGuardian.guardian_id = 2
```

That should do.